# Best Pythonic way to replace any non-A-Z, non numbers, with a dash

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have the following string:

```
my_str = "1,123_$ABC_NN&_XX,154440480,YVH?ADXX,,503,TCCTGA,503,TATCCTCT,,,154440480"
```

I want to keep all the A-Z, 0-9, dash and underscores and replace EVERYTHING else with a dash.  What is the best Pythonic way to do this?

I have done this, it works but its messy:

```
my_str.replace('#','-').replace('!','-').replace('"','-').replace('$','-').replace('%','-').replace('^','-').replace('&','-').replace('*','-').replace('(','-').replace(')','-').replace('@','-').replace('~','-').replace(';','-').replace(':','-').replace('[','-').replace(']','-').replace('{','-').replace('}','-').replace('?','-').replace('/','-').replace('>','-').replace('<','-').replace('|','-').replace('\\','-').replace(' ','-')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> my_str = "1,123_$ABC_NN&_XX,154440480,YVH?ADXX,,503,TCCTGA,503,TATCCTCT,,,154440480"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w-]', '-', my_str)
'1-123_-ABC_NN-_XX-154440480-YVH-ADXX--503-TCCTGA-503-TATCCTCT---154440480'
```

If you want to avoid multiple hyphens then:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w-]+', '-', my_str)
'1-123_-ABC_NN-_XX-154440480-YVH-ADXX-503-TCCTGA-503-TATCCTCT-154440480'
```

`[^\w-]` matches any character that is not word char (includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it this way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^A-Z0-9-_]', '-', my_str)
'1-123_-ABC_NN-_XX-154440480-YVH-ADXX--503-TCCTGA-503-TATCCTCT---154440480'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this a lot, you could pre-build a translation table and then apply it to each string. This would be very fast if a lot of strings are being processed:

```
my_trans_list = ['-'] * 256

for x in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-':
    my_trans_list[ord(x)] = x

my_trans = ''.join(my_trans_list)

my_str = "1,123_$ABC_NN&_XX,154440480,YVH?ADXX,,503,TCCTGA,503,TATCCTCT,,,154440480"
print my_str.translate(my_trans)
```

This would display:

```
1-123_-ABC_NN-_XX-154440480-YVH-ADXX--503-TCCTGA-503-TATCCTCT---154440480
```

Tested in Python 2.7.6